# Does molly-guard interfere with apcupsd shutdown process?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh

Does molly-guard interfere with apcupsd's shutdown process for the master or slave? I have molly-guard installed on both the apcupsd master and slave machines and am unable to test if it will interfere with the shutdown process.